# Get DB changes into SSAS-Projekt

Tags: sql, synchronization, ssas

I have a well working SSAS Projekt witch is connected to a SQL-Database. My problem is when i added new records to some of the database tables the entries didnt show up in the cube.
Already tried do deploy and refseh everything i found but the data wont show up in the cube.

Then i found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174928.aspx
Tried it with the Synchronize Database Wizard but the target and destionation server are not allowed to be on the same server. Sadly, in my case they are on the same server :-(.

Is there something i am doing wrong or do i miss a button/wizard or something to refresh the data in my cube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your relational data contents are updated (but the structure stays the same), what you need to do is to *process* the Analysis Services database. This causes the Analysis Services database to pull the data from the relational database and update the dimensions and cubes. You can process the whole database, or only parts of it, and there are different processing modes (update, full, ...), which are documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174774.aspx

The easiest way in  the beginning would be to do a "process full" of the whole Analysis Services database. You can do this e. g. by right-clicking the Analysis Services database in Management Studio, and selecting "Process".